# Is it possible to make VIM display line numbers?

Tags: linux, vim, numbers, line

I have the need to analyze very large files in VIM (only command mode I can use).
Is it possible to configure VIM to display line numbers?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Do `:set number` to display line numbers.

Comment: if you want to disable :set nonumber

Comment: And as a super-bonus, `:set relativenumber` to see the numbers as distance from the line the cursor is on! (Vim 7.3+)

Comment: `:set ruler` is sometime useful when you want to save screen column width for actual data.  it shows only current cursor position at the bottom.  since it wont hurt much I use it as default

Comment: `nmap <silent> <F11> :exec &nu==&rnu? "se nu!" : "se rnu!"<CR>` change between number, nonumber and relativenumber - put this in your ~/.vimrc (chose your favorite keys), if ~/.vimrc dont has create that

Comment: @user107745:  Or shorter: `:exe'se'&nu+&rnu?'rnu!':'nu'`.  By the way, do not use `nmap` instead of `nnoremap` until you know what you are doing and absolutely need the former.

Comment: Use `:se nu` `:se nonu` `:se rnu` `:se nornu` when switching just for a short time from within vim.

Answer (score 4):

`:set nu` shortcut of doing the same thing as `:set number`. unset it with `:set nonu`. Type `:help nonu` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Command `:set number` or `:set nu` will display line numbers

Command `:set nonumber` or `:set nonu` will remove line numbers

To enable the display of line numbers permanently (on startup) add `set number` to your `~/.vimrc`